# use vue-konva with a cdn and without a ES6 compiler

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, konvajs

It´s posible to use vue-konva with a cdn and without a ES6 compiler, I try the next code, provided in this page https://konvajs.github.io/docs/vue/

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
    <meta http-equiv='x-ua-compatible' content='ie=edge'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='app'>
      <v-stage ref="stage" :config="configKonva">
        <v-layer ref="layer">
          <v-circle :config="configCircle"></v-circle>
        </v-layer>
      </v-stage>
    </div>
    <!--1. Link Vue Javascript & Konva-->
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/konva/1.7.6/konva.js'></script>
    <!--2. Link VueKonva Javascript (Plugin automatically installed)-->
    <script src='./lib/vue-konva.min.js'></script>
    <script>
      // 3. Create the Vue instance
      new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          configKonva: {
            width: 200,
            height: 200
          },
          configCircle: {
            x: 100,
            y: 100,
            radius: 70,
            fill: 'red',
            stroke: 'black',
            strokeWidth: 4
          }
        }
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the ./lib/vue-konva.min.js dosn´t exist and when I remove that line

> vue.js:616 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> vue.js:616 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
>
> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
> correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
> option.

Comment: `src='./lib/vue-konva.min.js'` is a relative path. You need to have this file on your local or link to a cdn.

Comment: I think the file was removed in the `vue-konva` v2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As comment, `src='./lib/vue-konva.min.js'` is a relative path. You need to have this file on your local or CDN link

Here you can you an old version from [jsDelivr](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-konva@1.0.7/lib/vue-konva.min.js)

Change your code

```
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-konva@1.0.7/lib/vue-konva.min.js'>
</script>
```

[Demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/oJjqgm)